# SQL JOIN tables where have multiple instances of the same id

Tags: php, mysql, join, subquery

I have two tables within the same database; tableA has the `date` I need while tableB has the `cost`. These tables are like an archive of changing dates and costs so a single item is repeated multiple times but I only want the most recent `date` and lowest `cost`.

Data example:

**tableA**

```
  LocalSKU: aaa-aaa1 date: 12/1/1
  LocalSKU: aaa-aaa1 date: 11/1/3
  LocalSKU: aaa-aaa1 date: 10/2/1
```

**tableB**

```
  SKU: aaa-aaa1 cost: 0.15
  SKU: aaa-aaa1 cost: 5
  SKU: aaa-aaa1 cost: 0
```

Desired result:

```
SKU: aaa-aaa1 date: 12/1/1 cost: 0
```

I've tried a simple query to pull back a single result with this query:

```
SELECT MAX(date) 
FROM tableA 
WHERE LocalSKU = (SELECT MIN(cost) 
                  FROM tableB 
                  WHERE SKU = tableB.LocalSKU GROUP BY SKU);
```

which yielded 0 results.

I'm new to subquerying and joining, is there a single query that can be made to get the desired result? I'm able to get the information I want in separate queries, but I got stuck trying to merge the arrays to combine the desired information.

Help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Join the tables and use the aggregation function on the result.

```
SELECT a.localsku, MIN(cost), MAX(date)
FROM tableA
JOIN tableB ON a.localsku = b.sku
GROUP BY a.localsku
```

Actually, it will probably be more performant to do the grouping first and then join the subqueries, since joining large tables is expensive.

```
SELECT a.localsku, a.date, b.cost
FROM (
    SELECT localsku, MAX(date) AS date
    FROM tableA
    GROUP BY localsku) AS a
JOIN (
    SELECT sku, MIN(cost) as cost
    FROM tableB
    GROUP BY sku) AS b
ON a.localsku = b.sku
```

Comment: Woah, WOAH - this is amazing and it worked! Is there some documentation, that's a noob-friendly read, where this is broken down so I can build my own in the future?

Comment: [A visual explanation of SQL joins](https://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/)